# React | Formik Async Validatin, cannot read .then of undefined

Tags: reactjs, promise, async-await, react-proptypes, formik

I am using React and Formik to handle my forms. In a component, I have a simple `input` text. That text is handled for error if being empty by formik. The problem is, I also want to asynchronously handle server validation (if the input.target.value already exist in the database).

Formik provides that functionality, but I am obviously doing something wrong because I get the following error.

> Cannot read property .then of undefined

Code Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nkm2zyy4z0

So far, I have done the following. According to formik documentation:

```
    const asyncValidation = values =>
      listItems.then(data => {
        const errors ={};
        if (data.includes(values.name)) {
          errors.name = 'Username already exist';
        }
        if (!data.include(values.name) {
          throw errors;
        }
      });
```

I also tried to create another iteration of the asyncValidation promise, as you see below:

```
const asyncValidation = values =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const errors = {};
    if (listGroups.includes(values.name)) {
      console.log(errors)
      errors.email = 'Required';
    }

    if (!listGroups.includes(values.name)) {
      console.log(errors)
      reject(errors);
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });
```

But still, I get an error:

> index.jsx:21 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Not sure what to do. Name if a property of the values object. If I print on the console, the results, it will print this:

```
{name: "generalGroup1", description: ""}
description: ""
name: "generalGroup1"
__proto__: Object
```

**Not sure what is wrong here...**

Here, formik uses promises to handle this async functionality. I am a little perplex, on what error should be thrown. Maybe I made the mistake here, since I want to basically say. `If the value matches something in the database, say that it already exists. If not don't throw any error.`

Promises need to throw errors, so what should I do there, and how should I solve my console error.

I am also using a built in service to call the list of items from the API, in order to check against the value being on the input.

```
export const listItems = () => {
  const options = {
    method: httpMethod.GET,
    url: endpoint.LIST_ITEMS
  };
  return Instance(options);
};
```

Below is the part of the component relevant to the input field:

```
class ItemDetailsForm extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    ...formPropTypes,
    data: PropTypes.object
  };

  handleSubmit = values => {
    const { id, onSubmit } = this.props;
    onSubmit(id, values);
    asyncValidation();
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ ...data }}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        render={({ values, touched, errors, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-3">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="itemName">
                    Item name <span className="text-danger">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    value={values.name}
                    name="name"
                    className={classNames('form-control', {
                      'is-invalid': errors.name && touched.name
                    })}
                    id="itemsName"
                    placeholder="Some Item"
                  />
                  {!!errors.name && touched.name && (
                    <div className="text-danger">{errors.name}</div>
                  )}
                </div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ItemDetailsForm;
```

I have followed the formik docs, almost to the teeth, but something is obviously wrong. Can you help a bit. I am relatively new to programming, so if you could explain my mistake it would be great.

Comment: I would suggest to make a quick code sandbox with your code. It will be easier to debug and get help

Comment: I have created the Sandbox here. Obviously I cannot share every bit of code, cause it will get into a labyrinth of files, but the basic functionality is here. Check it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/nkm2zyy4z0

Comment: Another option here, is to use observables. I am using `redux-observables` and usually do this with epics, but I am having a little bit of trouble here, with the operators I need to use. I would rather use formik, but if you have a way to solve this with observables please advice.